# Ionic 2 button in ion-list. How can I know which button actually the user clicked?

Tags: ionic-framework, angular2-template

I have an ion-list with button per list items.
How can I know which item of the button the user is actually clicked?

```
<ion-list>
<ion-item *ngFor="let item of items">
<h2>{{item.name}}</h2>
<p>{{item.description}}</p>
<button ion-button clear item-right (click)="itemClicked($event)">View</button>
</ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

My environment as below

```
Cordova CLI: 6.5.0
Ionic Framework Version: 3.0.1
Ionic CLI Version: 2.2.2
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.2.1
Ionic App Scripts Version: 1.3.0
ios-deploy version: 1.9.1
ios-sim version: 5.0.13
OS: macOS Sierra
Node Version: v7.7.1
Xcode version: Xcode 8.3.2 Build version 8E2002
```

Thank you.

Comment: Can I add some HTML attribute to the button or add value to the button, so that I can pass the value on "itemClicked" ?

Answer (score 0):

You can send multiple arguments to the function called by `click` :

`itemClicked($event, item.id)` should solve your problem.